# Chrom viewport size for 1366x768 screen resolution?

Tags: google-chrome, screen-resolution

What is chrome's viewport size in 1366x768 resolution screens? Any link suggestions where I can find a coverter for this?

Comment: Height will vary depending on the user's taskbar size and whether they show bookmark bar, but width should be very similar, isn't it? You can just try it yourself by temporarily resizing your screen resolution.

Comment: I have same question

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on an old laptop of mine, height turned out to be 615px for Windows 10 and 618px for Windows 7 (with the Bookmarks bar visible). Width is - of course - 1366px.